# Why does .apply() not apply rotation like I expect?

Tags: numpy, scipy

```
(Pdb) R.from_matrix(R_xy).apply(centered_points[599,:])
array([-0.02405325,  0.00502445,  0.06892317])
(Pdb) (R_xy @ centered_points[599,:].T).T
array([-0.02449478,  0.00437224,  0.06888685])
```

I would expect the second line to be proper application of a rotation to centered_points. centered_points is a 1024, 3 vector. Visually, when I check the result, #2 is correct, and Scipy is wrong. What gives?

Comment: Could you please provide `R_xy` and `centered_points[599, :]`, otherwise it is hard to reproduce your problem and help you.

Answer (score 1):

I discovered the issue: I was generating R_xy from non-perfectly orthogonal vectors. This messes up all calculations with rot.apply

Answer (score 0):

I can not reproduce this behaviour:

```py
from scipy.spatial.transform import Rotation

rot = Rotation.from_quat((0.7, 0.6, 0.5, 0.4))
# array([[ 0.03174603,  0.34920635,  0.93650794],
#        [ 0.98412698, -0.17460317,  0.03174603],
#        [ 0.17460317,  0.92063492, -0.34920635]])

x = [3, 2, 1]
y1 = rot.as_matrix() @ x
# array([1.73015873, 2.63492063, 2.01587302])
y2 = rot.apply(x)
# array([1.73015873, 2.63492063, 2.01587302])
```